# How to prepare FATCA data transmission files with open source tools

Tags: aes, rsa

Here is the context: to transmit FATCA data to US IRS service the IDES protocol defines [the following steps](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Corporations/IDES-Data-Transmission-and-File-Preparation)

1. sign the XML `Payload.xml` file with enveloping signature, SHA-256 with RSA private key, as `Payload-signed.xml`.
2. pack the signed XML `Payload-signed.xml` file into a zip file `Payload.zip`
3. generate a single-usage 32 bytes key for AES-256
4. encrypt the Zip archive `Payload.zip` with AES-256 as `Payload`
5. encrypt the AES with RSA public key for exchange as `Key`
6. bundle encrypted AES key `Key` and encrypted zip file `Payload` in a Zip archive

How to implement this process with existing open source tools (with preference for Linux platform) ?

Remark: [this project](https://github.com/IRSgov/IDES-Data-Preparation-Dot-Net) demonstrates how to do it with .Net

Comment: This is a programming question more than an InfoSec question. You have the steps, you just need the commands/program to do it.

Comment: From my point of view, this post matches the following topics "security tools" and "using cryptography". It does not sound relevant for "SuperUser", so probably you should migrate it to "StackOverflow" (as a by default choice). Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is the process I have designed with available Linux tools. Care to all file names (case sensitive) and replace `MyOrgGIIN` with your organisation's GIIN identifier.

1. There is high risk that quotation marks and comas are present in your FATCA XML file. Expunge these characters from the XML file to [avoid failure at submission](https://www.reddit.com/r/FATCA/comments/30zqib/were_getting_a_ntd_alert_when_sending_our_data/) (and some others like hash and double dash, read [this PDF](http://www.irs.gov/pub/fatca/fatcareportsicmmnotificationsuserguide.pdf) for details).
2. Include your `ftc:FATCA_OECD` XML structure into an enveloping signature template specifying expected cipher and hash methods (`Payload.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <Reference URI="#FATCA">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue></DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509SubjectName></X509SubjectName>
      <X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
  <Object Id="FATCA">
    <ftc:FATCA_OECD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1" xmlns:ftc="urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1" 
      xmlns:iso="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1" 
      xmlns:sfa="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v1" version="1.1">

      [... your data ...]

    </ftc:FATCA_OECD>
  </Object>
</Signature>
```

3. Generate XML signature in prepared template with `xmlsec1`, it will fill empty nodes:

`xmlsec1 --sign --output MyOrgGIIN_Payload.xml --pkcs12 myorg_ssl_certificate.p12 --pwd pkcs12password Playload.xml`

4. Compress signed XML payload as zip archive

`zip MyOrgGIIN_Payload.zip MyOrgGIIN_Payload.xml`

5. Generate a single usage 32 bytes key

`dd if=/dev/random of=mySingleUsageAesKey bs=8 count=4`

6. Display the 32 bytes as hexadecimal sequence (64 characters)

`xxd -c 32 -p mySingleUsageAesKey`

7. Encrypt your `Payload.zip` file with AES-256 passing your hexadecimal key as `-K` option

`openssl aes-256-ecb -nosalt -K HexaSequenceForMySingleUsageAesKey -in MyOrgGIIN_Payload.zip -out MyOrgGIIN_Payload`

8. Encrypt the AES key with IRS RSA public key

`openssl rsautl -encrypt -certin -inkey IRSpublickey.cer -in mySingleUsageAesKey -out 000000.00000.TA.840_Key`

9. Generate a timestamp with `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%2NZ"`
10. Create metadata file using this timestamp from IDES site as `MyOrgGIIN_Metadata.xml`
11. Pack your metadata, encrypted payload and encrypted AES key in transmission data archive

`zip TIMESTAMP_MyOrgGIIN.zip MyOrgGIIN_Metadata.xml MyOrgGIIN_Payload 000000.00000.TA.840_Key`

Now submit and react to errors notification.